# PHP : understand the CURL timeout

Tags: php, curl, get

From a php page, i have to do a get to another php file.
I don't care to wait for the response of the get or know whether it is successful or not.

The file called could end the script also in 5-6 seconds, so i don't know how to handle the get timeout considering what has been said before.

The code is this

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://mywebsite/myfile.php'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1);
$content = trim(curl_exec($ch));
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: if you don't "don't care to wait for the response or to know whether it is successful or not" so... why try to load it?

Comment: It sounds ominously like you're trying to use a GET request to achieve something that should be done with a POST ...

Comment: The cURL timeout defines how long curl will wait for a response to come. It defines not the maximum execution time of the called script. The latter has to be handled on the "other" side.

Comment: For better understanding: is this some kind of web hook you try to implement? Just hitting a URL without caring for the response?

Comment: @BobbyJack effectively in this case only needed POST..

Comment: @jossif , yes, because the file called should simply create a file on the server (taking some information from a web page)..

Answer (score 0):

For the first task (Where you don't need to wait for response )you can start new background process and below that write code which will redirect you on another page.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you **definitely** shouldn't be creating a file on the server in response to a GET request. Even as a side-effect, it's less than ideal; as the main purpose of the request, it just doesn't make sense.

If you *were* doing this as a POST, you'd still have the same issue to work with, however. In that case, if the action can't be guaranteed to happen quickly enough to be acceptable in the context of HTTP, you'll need to hive it off somewhere else. E.g. make your HTTP request send a message to some other system which then works in parallel whilst the HTTP response is free to be sent back immediately.